# Using DirectX data-structures and API's from a static library giving Access-Violation Errors.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, directx, static-libraries

I have an application which uses DirectX data-structures and APIs and it works fine as a Standalone application too.But I want to integrate  it in another application as a static library. But when I do so I start getting Access Violation errors.Where am I going wrong?

IDirectInputDevice8* DIKeybd;
void DetectInput(double time)
{

```
DIMOUSESTATE mouseCurrState;
BYTE keyboardState[256];

DIKeybd->Acquire(); //Place where I am receiving error.
DIMouse->Acquire();

DIMouse->GetDeviceState(sizeof(DIMOUSESTATE), &mouseCurrState);
DIKeybd->GetDeviceState(sizeof(keyboardState), &keyboardState);

// If escape then ask for window to destroy
/*if(keyboardState[DIK_ESCAPE] & 0x80)
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);*/

if(keyboardState[DIK_F5] & 0x80)
    Reset();

if(keyboardState[DIK_RETURN] & 0x80)
    enter = 1;
```

Error- 
Unhandled exception at 0x013d9b5d in execLensCurveCorrection.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Is `DIKeybd` NULL? How do you initialise it?

Comment: IDirectInputDevice8* DIKeybd;

Comment: Then you will get that kind of error! You just defined a variable to hold a pointer to a DirectX interface but you didn't initialise it by creating an input device. Compare the usage of this variable in the code that works.